# How to get the date with specific hour and minute of today from "HH:mm" string in Objecive-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a time string like "HH:mm" format and I want to get a `NSDate` object of today at that time.

I am using `NSDateFormatter` but it not work.

Here is my code:

```objectivec
NSString *dateString = @"21:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
// date:    __NSTaggedDate *    2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC 0xfa629653dac0e51b
```

I want the `date` to be `2022-10-27 21:00:00`;

Comment: Use `-[NSCalendar dateBySettingHour:minute:second:ofDate:options:]`?

Comment: @Larme I want to use `NSDateFormatter` because I have the "HH:mm" date string from config. Sorry I will modify my question.

Comment: Does `NSDateFormatter` have any properties you could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultDate` property on NSDateFormatter does what you want :

```
NSString *dateString = @"21:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
dateFormatter.defaultDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
// 2022-10-27 20:00:26 UTC
```